# Absolute values nested multiple times

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, absolute-value

Is there any algorithm to quickly determine "zero points" (i.e. points with undefined derivation) of absolute values functions which are nested multiple times? I do know, that any part of this piecewise function is going to be linear or constant (no exponential, trigonometry, logarithm, polynomial, rational, nothing more "difficult" than linear)

For example, given function such as this? $f(x) = |||||||x|-32|-16|-8|-4x|-2|+|||||x-33|-17|-9|-5|-3|-5|-2-14$

I need to find some general algorithm (usable in programming homework, where no graphing tools are available), these coefficients can vary. Any help is appreciated, I believe I'm fairly good at math, but this seems as unsolvable problem to me, so just pointing out into the right direction might really help.

Thanks a lot for any direction.

Comment: Create an algorithm that works from the inside towards the outside. It needs to branch in every step. Divide the function at the $+$ sign and solve separately, and put it together later. For example say that you have $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$. Lets look at $f_1(x)$. You look at the innermost absolute value $|x|$, you get 2 cases, now look at $||x|-32|$ and get 4 cases. 
At the end you'll have a lot of cases. Try to figure it, I hope I gave you a starting idea.

Comment: Well, thank you, but "unfortunately" I already had this idea. And no goddamn idea how to code it..

Comment: Oh you just don't know the coding. First of all it is important to get the right input function, so you will need to define what your input will look like. If you have a well defined input then you explain the computer the difference between different nesting levels. I'm not sure what the best way would be to store the function so you can easily go through the algorithm. You can define functions like $g_1(x)=|x|, g_2(x)=|g_1(x)-32|\dots$, maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: Well.. Might say that, BUT.. The point of this homework is to be code as fast algorithm as it can possibly get. And I don't really know how to store it efficiently, that's the point. And I asked this before I even started coding, because I hoped there would be faster way than this..

Comment: I really don't know on what level you are, or if you wanted something numerical or analytical. Well then, expand your question with the info you gave me maybe somebody else can help more. Last suggestion, try this: Form two arrays, one storing constants and one storing coefficients. Create a function(that will do the smart work) that you call in a loop with the results of the last iteration as one of the parameters. Generally speaking however you do this will be blazingly fast, except for really big systems. You can ask your question [stackoveflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) too.